# jQuery plugin to show the contents of a specific div on an external page?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-plugins

Scenario:

Say I am on an invoice details page.  I have a customer name label and I want to be able to load customer details into a popup tooltip on mouseover of the label.

The contents of this tooltip should come from the contents of a **specific div** on an external page, for example:

ExternalURL: Customers.aspx?CustomerID=224
ExternalDIV: CustomerDetail

So, the URL pulls up the details for a specific customer, and by passing the div name, I don't display the header or any extraneous information that would normally be displayed when doing a proper navigation to the page.  The reason for wanting to call an external page is so I can popup customer details from any page with very little coding.

I swear I found a plugin that does this a few months ago but can't seem to track it down now....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as that external page is on the same domain, you can do this using [jQuery's ajax load](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) function.

Par example:

```
$("#currentDiv").load("/Customers.aspx?CustomerID=224 #CustomerDetail");
```

Comment: From your question, it looked like your main concern was how to get the content. The .load() function will do exactly what you need.  If you need a tooltip/popup, just do a google search for jQuery tooltip -- there are a couple of solutions out there that you could use.

Comment: I've been doing lots of googling and have yet to find a jQuery plugin that can both a) Load an external URL, b) in a popup tooltip, and c) Show only the contents of a certain DIV

Comment: (a) and (c) are achieved with the .load() function.  (b) is achieved through a tooltip plugin, any number of which you can find online. If you're looking for a plugin that does all three without you having to put forth any more effort than that, well... I don't know what to tell you.  All the pieces are there for you to take advantage of. Give it a shot.

Comment: Ah, ok.....I didn't realize that jQuery selectors (ie: #CustomerDetail in your example) were fully supported in the load function.  This should make pretty much anything possible, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Might work:

http://rndnext.blogspot.com/2009/02/jquery-ajax-tooltip.html

He has the external page name (personajax.aspx) and div name (personPopupResult) hardcoded, but these could be passed as parameters, just as he is passing 'page' and 'guid' as parameters.